# Is it possible to construct an "infinite" string?

Tags: c++, string, infinite

Is there any real sequence of characters that always compares greater than any other string?

My first thought was that a string constructed like so:

```
std::basic_string<T>(std::string::max_size(), std::numeric_limits<T>::max())
```

Would do the trick, provided that the fact that it would almost definitely fail to work isn't such a big issue. So I presume this kind of hackery could only be accomplished in Unicode, if it can be accomplished at all. I've never heard of anything that would indicate that it really *is* possible, but neither have I heard tell that it *isn't*, and I'm curious.

Any thoughts on how to achieve this without a `possibly_infinite<basic_string<T>>`?

Comment: Why do you need such a thing?

Comment: Describe the goal, not the step: http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#goal

Comment: Some of these other peoples problems make me feel good about my own problems.

Comment: Ropes allow strings of length INT_MAX with very small memory usage, i think

Comment: I fail to see a purpose here. What would you use it for? You can't print it, etc. Comparisons? Why compare something with an infinite string, you already know the result.

Comment: I don't *need* it, really. I'm fully aware of other, better solutions, so I don't need an answer to any question but this one. I'm just wondering if it's even *possible* to do it in a slightly more clever, hackish way.

Comment: @GMan: How about arbitrary ranges? For example, `>"bar"` implies `"bar"..string_infinity`, and to test whether `"foo"` is in that range, it's necessary to test `"bar" < "foo"` and `"foo" < string_infinity`.

Comment: @Jon: Not sure I understand you there.

Comment: @GMan: To test whether X is in an interval (A, B), you need to test A < X and X < B. Now say you want to construct arbitrary intervals of strings and allow them to be unbounded on either the left or right. The *minimum* value of a string is `""`, and `"" < X` is always true. So what is the *maximum* value, and is this representable in a reasonable amount of memory?

Comment: @litb: was about to mention std::rope [crope/wrope] then I saw your comment...

Comment: What do you want to happen when you compare the infinite string with itself?

Comment: ∞ < ∞ is false for numbers, and so should it be for strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that you compare strings using their character value. I.e. one character acts like a digit, a longer string is greater than shorter string, etc.

> s there any real sequence of characters that always compares greater than any other string?

No, because:

1. Let's assume there is a string *s* that is always greater than any other string.
2. If you make a copy of *s*, the copy will be equal to *s*. Equal means "not greater". Therefore there can be a string that is not greater than *s*.
3. If you make a copy of *s* and append one character at the end, it will be greater than original *s*. Therefore there can be a string that is greater than *s*.
4. Which means, it is not possible to make *s*.

I.e.

A string *s* that is always greater than any other string cannot exist. A copy of *s* (copy == other string) will be equal to *s*, and "equal" means "not greater".
A string *s* that is always greater or equal to any other string, can exist if a maximum string size has a reasonable limit. Without a size limit, it will be possible to take a copy of *s*, append one character at the end, and get a string that is greater than *s*.

In my opinion, the proper solution would be to introduce some kind of special string object that represents infinitely "large" string, and write a comparison operator for that object and standard string. Also, in this case you may need custom string class.

It is possible to make string that is always less or equal to any other string. Zero length string will be exactly that - always smaller than anything else, and equal to other zero-length strings.

Or you could write counter-intuitive comparison routine where shorter string is greater than longer string, but in this case next code maintainer will hate you, so it is not a good idea.

Not sure why would you ever need something like that, though.

Comment: Given that there is no magical Unicode representation of such a string, and that it's infeasible to actually *use* a string of maximum length, I guess this is my answer.

Comment: Hate to bring up an old question, but surely by this logic there is no largest integer?

Comment: @katrielalex: "largest" means "greater or equal" to any other value. It doesn't mean "always greater than any other value". For int32, int64, int16, there will be an integer that is greater or equal to any other integer of same type. For unsigned int32 that'll be 2^32-1 - i.e. 0xffffffff. For bignums, depending on implementation it is possible that there will be no integer that is always greater than any other - you can take that integer and add 1 to it to get larger value (until you run out of memory). Although (for bignums) you can introduce "infinity" constant which will be largest integer.

Answer (score 3):

You probably need a custom comparator, for which you define a magic "infinite string" value and which will always treat that value as greater than any other.

Comment: I'm looking specifically for a non-magical solution, being already aware of a suitable magical one. Thanks, though.

Comment: @JS: Nothing, particularly. That's actually what I've already done, in a way. I was just looking for alternate routes. And You said "magic" first. :P

Comment: Is it possible to have a string larger than 2GB? Since string.length is an int, what happens if you have a string larger than 2147483647 characters?

Comment: @diadem: `string::length` does not necessarily need to be a 32 bit int, but is rather implementation defined. In fact even in 32 bit systems it can be (in gcc it is) an unsigned 32 bit int (up to 4G), and in 64bit macosx it is a 64bit unsigned int, so it **can** grow beyond the 2Gb limit --if you only take into account the types, the OS might limit memory allocations, or the compiler can limit in cases the whole memory for a program...

Answer (score 3):

Unicode solves a lot of problems, but not that one.  Unicode is just a different encoding for a character, 1, 2 or 4 bytes, they are still stored in a plain array.  You can use infinite strings when you find a machine with infinite memory.

Answer (score 2):

[Yes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zorn%27s_lemma). How you do it, I have no idea :)

Comment: +1 for out-of-the-box thinking!  But -1 because a maximal element in the set-theoretic sense can still compare equal to some other element, and Jon wants strictly greater than.  So, no upvote, but thanks for the laugh!

Answer (score 1):

You should try to state what you intend to achieve and what your requirements are. In particular, does it **have** to be a string? is there *any* limitation on the domain? do they need to be compared with `<`?

You can use a non-string type:

```
struct infinite_string {};
bool operator<( std::string const & , infinite_string const & ) {
   return true;
}
bool operator<( infinite_string const &, std::string const & ) {
   return false;
}
```

If you can use `std::lexicographical_compare` and you don't need to store it as a string, then you can write an infinite iterator:

```
template <typename CharT>
struct infinite_iterator
{
   CharT operator*() { return std::numeric_limits<CharT>::max(); }
   infinite_iterator& operator++() { return *this; }
   bool operator<( const infinite_iterator& ) { return true; }
   // all other stuff to make it proper
};
assert( std::lexicographical_compare( str.begin(), str.end(), 
                              infinite_iterator, infinite_iterator ) );
```

If you can use any other comparisson functor and your domain has some invalid you can use that to your advantage:

```
namespace detail {
   // assume that "\0\0\0\0\0" is not valid in your domain
   std::string const infinite( 5, 0 ); 
}
bool compare( std::string const & lhs, std::string const & rhs ) {
   if ( lhs == detail::infinite ) return false;
   if ( rhs == detail::infinite ) return true;
   return lhs < rhs;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you need an artificial bound within a space of objects that *isn't* bounded, the standard trick is to add an extra element and define a new comparison operator that enforces your property.

Or implement lazy strings.

Comment: Thanks, that is the solution I've already used. By "lazy strings", do you mean a string that is secretly a generator?

Comment: yes, for example in haskell syntax: [ Data.Char.chr 255 | i <- [1..]]

(just don't compare it with itself)

Answer (score 0):

Well if you were to dynamically construct a string of equal length as the one that you are comparing to and fill it with the highest ASCII code available (7F for normal ASCII or FF for extended) you would be guaranteed that this string would compare equal to or greater than the one you compare it to.

Answer (score 0):

What's your comparator?

Based on that, you can construct something that is the 'top' of your lattice.